# Define a button's onclick event in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, onclick

I have a `<button>` in order to scroll the page to a specific DIV when clicked (`#contact`)

```
<button onclick="location.href='#contact';">Click Me</button>
```

How to define it in Javascript?

```
$('button[onclick^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
// Some stuffs here...
});
```

I'm using this to animate the scrolling from a `button` to a DIV:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
.preventDefault();
var target = this.hash,
$target = $(target);
$('html, body').stop().animate({
'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
}, 900, 'swing', function () {
window.location.hash = target;
});
});
```

But it works only on `a href`s because of its `a[href^="#"]`. So I'm interested to make it work on my `<button>`s

Comment: Can't you do this with an anchor element and no JS at all?

Comment: I don't want to duplicate my `button`'s style to a `a` tag, also I'm interested to learn sth new instead of using `<a href..>`

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for. Do you want to bind the event handler without jQuery?

Comment: Your question says 'Define a button's on click event'. If that's what you want to know, something along lines of $('button').click(function(e){//logic}) would work (which already seems there in your question). Please be a little more elaborate if that is not what you want.

Comment: I added more information to the question, so is it understandable now or need more explain?

Comment: 'button[onclick^="location.href=\'#"]'

Comment: Do you mean `$('button[onclick^="location.href=\'#"]').on('click',function (e) {` ? It don't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the button(s)

```
<button class="jumper" data-href="#contact">Click Me</button>
```

Attach the click event.

```
$('button.jumper').click(function (e) {
    // new location
    location.href= $(this).data().href;
});
```

Comment: You're using jQuery there. Pure JS: `object.onclick=function(){SomeJavaScriptCode};`

Comment: @ArthurKovacs Hmmm... what if the title of this post would say: "Define a button's onclick event in Jquery"? oh... guess what... it is the title of this post. Joking. Of course the straightforward way using pure old JS is the best, but he asked for JQ.

Comment: Yeah, "... event in Jquery", apparently I missed the title and the first line from the question itself put me in JavaScript  mode :) . No prb.

Comment: But it's impossible to add the Jquery scroll animation to this pure JS method.

Comment: You replace my entire click handler with your click handler from your question. Just need to change this line  $target = $(target); to this line $target = $($(this).data().href);

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with anchor tag `<a>`

```
Top <a href="#bottom">Go to Bottom</a>

<div id="bottom">
Bottom
</div>
```

Refer above sample code

Answer (score 0):

**Html**

```
<button id="clicker" onclick="location.href='#contact';">Click Me</button>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#clicker').click(function (e) {
  $.scrollTo($('#somediv'), 300);
});
```

Comment: Should the `#somediv` be same as `#contact`? I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery

for your button' **s**

```
$('button[onclick^="location.href=\'#"]').on('click',function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var target = this.hash,
 $target = $(target);
 $('html, body').stop().animate({
  'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
 }, 900, 'swing', function () {
  window.location.hash = target;
 });
});
```

**A** jQuery way to getthe buttons that contain a click event with the value 'location.href=#'

```
$('button[onclick^="location.href=\'#"]').on('click',function (e) {
 // Some stuffs here...
}
```

**Ways to find/create buttons and define onclick event in javascript:**

Search the first button (note [0])

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onclick=function(){
 location.href='#contact';
}
```

get the button by id (note 'myButton')

```
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick=function(){
 location.href='#contact';
}
```

create the whole button dynamically and add it to the body

```
var button=document.createElement('button');
button.onclick=function(){
 location.href='#contact';
}
document.body.appendChild(button);
```

modern ways to find the button

```
var button=document.querySelector('button');

var button=document.querySelectorAll('button')[0];
```

**B** pure javascript way to getthe buttons that contain a click event with the value 'location.href=#'

```
var buttons=document.querySelectorAll('button[onclick^="location.href=\'#"]');
```

non ie events

```
button.addEventListener('click',function(){
 location.href='#contact';
},false);
```

ie events

```
button.attachEvent('onclick',function(){
 location.href='#contact';
});
```

any questions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```html
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" onclick="myfunction()">
```

**jQuery:**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 function myfunction() 
 {
    // do whatever you want
 }
</script>
```